# Why does scp not work when I run it on a remote server to copy back to my local machine?

Tags: ssh, scp

When I try to get a file from a remote server I can do either of the following

```
1) Login to the remote server. 
     $ ssh root@remoteserverip
       password:
     $ scp theFileIwant myname@myserverip:/home/

2) Without logging to remote server
     $ scp root@remoteserverip:/root/theFileIwant /home/
```

Usually both methods works in all our intranet systems.

But when the remote server is another network only method 2 is working for me. Method 1 is always timing out.

Can anyone point the (obvious probably) answer

Comment: Tried putting `localhost:/path/to/the/file` ?

Comment: In Method 1: can you ssh to "root@remoteserverip" ?

Comment: yes I can ssh to the remote server alright. Once I login to that remote server I can't scp the files to my local

Comment: Can you ssh from the remoteserver to myserver? Is there a Firewall between the two networks?

Comment: The server in the "other network" might be behind a router that "NAT"s your internal network, so "myserverip" is not routed. Or there is some firewall that does not let you connect via SSL from the outside. After `ssh root@remoteserverip` try to `ping myserverip` if iti s accessible, and if yes, try `ssh myname@myserverip` to see if SSL is allowed.

Comment: After ssh root@remoteserverip I tried pinging to my ip.
My ip is not reachable. So I guess there is some firewall inbetween the machines. :(

Answer (score 3):

As stated by commenters, there may be several reasons why you can't connect back to myserverip. In that case, you can use ssh`s forward feature:

```
 (myserverip)$ ssh -R 2002:localhost:22 root@remoteserverip
   password:
 (remoteserver)$ scp -P 2002 theFileIwant myname@localhost:/home/
```

Comment: Thanks @xhienne. I tries as you mentioned. Still I cant do the scp using method1. What I am curious about is what is difference between method 1 and method 2. What is method 2 doing which is allowed by the firewall (I am assuming there is a fire wall between the servers.). What is method1 doing that is blocked by the firewall

Comment: @TywinLannister In method 1,  remoteserverip connects to scp port on myserverip. In method 2, myserverip connects to scp port on remoteserverip. A firewall typicall allows one direction and forbids the other. And this is without mentioning NAT which may prevent any direct connection to myserverip. Note that in any case, my method should work if you have an ssh server properly configured on myserverip, since it uses an ssh tunnel established during the first connection.